# The type or namespace name 'Cecil' does not exist in the namespace 'Mono'

Tags: c#, linux, mono, mono.cecil

I am new to C# programming .
I am trying to a compile a C# program which requires mono cecil

This is the code i am trying to compile
I dono how to add reference ...can someone help me out in this?

```
using System;
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono;

public class Program {
  public static void Main() {
    string infile = "in.exe";
    string outfile = "out.exe";
    Guid guid = Guid.Parse("12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab");
    AssemblyDefinition asm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(infile);
    ModuleDefinition mod = asm.MainModule;
    mod.Mvid = guid;
    asm.Write(outfile);
  }
}
```

I get the following error when i compile the program using mcs

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Cecil' does not exist in the namespace 'Mono'.Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I couldnt find Mono.Cecil.dll in /usr/lib/mono/4.0 & /usr/lib/mono/2.0.
Mono.Cecil.dll is present only in /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/

Kindly let me know if i am missing anything? and how do i get rid of this error ???

Regards

Puliyan

Comment: Regardless of its location, you must add the reference to that DLL to your project.  Have you done so?  The `using` alone is not enough.

Comment: Hey Don ,
I have made my question clear now ,sorry for inconvinence :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the compiler with the `-r`, `-pkg`, or `-lib` options where to find `Mono.Cecil.dll`.

A solution that always works is building the `.dll` from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/mono/cecil.git
cd cecil
xbuild /property:Configuration=net_4_0_Release
```

You can also use other configurations (e.g., `net_4_0_Debug`). Check the `.sln` or `.csproj` file for values. You'll find `Mono.Cecil.dll` in the `obj` subdirectory. You can then copy that library to whatever location you want and compile with `-r:/path/to/Mono.Cecil.dll`, `-lib:/path/to/libdirectory -r:Mono.Cecil.dll`, or if you're using MonoDevelop, add a reference to the library (in MonoDevelop, you should also be able to reference the project directly).

Cecil should normally also be available via the `pkg-config` mechanism; however, the `cecil.pc` file seems to be misconfigured. Normally, just using `-pkg:cecil` should suffice, but that appears to be broken and instead you have to use something like:

```
dmcs -r:`pkg-config --variable=Libraries`
```

in order to get the full path to `Mono.Cecil.dll` in the GAC.

Also, because mono is split up in a number of packages under Debian, you may have to install additional libraries if the above doesn't work (I don't know at the moment whether Cecil is part of the core package or not).